# Assigne permissions to SharePoint 2013 library item with workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, permissions, sharepoint-library

I have simple library and workflow on it, in library I have column with people and group

[image]

in workflow I am trying to set read permissions with impersonation step depends on this column but when I create item and workflow starts "Error Occurred" is displayed, I tried return field as string not Display Names, Semicolon Delimited but no success

[image]